# Rails error when failing a validate_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, erb

```
NoMethodError in Points#create

Showing /Volumes/EXTERNAL/Proiecte/Roadie/app/views/points/_form.html.erb where line #20 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.collect
Extracted source (around line #20):

17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :section %><br />
20:     <%= f.select(:section_id, [["Select a Section name", 0]] + @sections.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
21:   </div>
22: 
23:   <div class="field">
```

Essentially what happens here is, when one of the other fields in this form page (that is verified by the model) is missing, rails spews out the error posted above.

A section has many points and when creating a new point, a user should be able to choose a parent section.

Could anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the @sections instance variable is nil. Here is what I am guessing is happening based on your post:

You submit the form with incomplete data, which posts to create. The model is not saved, so you re-render the 'new' action. However, you forget to re-initialize the variables in the 'new' action in your controller.

In Rails, when you call render(:action => 'new'), it doesn't execute the code in the 'new' method of your controller. It simply renders the 'new' template, so you still need to set up any instance variables.

Comment: So how would I go reinitializing the variables in the new action?

Comment: in the end I modified my @sections to Section.all

Comment: Usually you can just call `new` again before rendering the action, or write an auxiliary method in your controller that sets up any necessary instance variables for your `new` and `create` actions.